# SQL Remove All Constraints Azure Friendly

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm doing some DB Admin with an Azure database and I need to perform queries like removing all constraints in the database.

sp_MSForEachTable is not available when working with Azure databases, so I'm working on a different way to do it.

I found a snippet that drops all tables here: http://edspencer.me.uk/2013/02/25/drop-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database-azure-friendly/ and tried modifying it to remove all constraints like I need to and came up with this result:

```
while(exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME != '__MigrationHistory'))
begin
    PRINT ('Disabling' + TABLE_NAME)
    declare @constraintOff nvarchar(2000)
    SELECT TOP 1 @constraintOff=('ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + '] ' + 'NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all')
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME != '__MigrationHistory'
    exec (@constraintOff)
    PRINT @constraintOff
end
```

It repeatedly tries to operate on the first item in the database, which would work fine if you were dropping everything but I need to loop through each table and disable its constraint like sp_MSForEachTable does.

Any tips? I've seen a few things here and there that claim to do this, but they're usually two or three page long scripts that do a lot of other stuff and they make my brain hurt.

UPDATE

still working on that query, it seems like something to this end might work better but still no dice:

```
declare @constraintOff nvarchar(2000)
SELECT @constraintOff=('ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + '] ' + 'NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
exec (@constraintOff)
PRINT @constraintOff
```

This one still only operates on one table, but at least it's not an infinite loop :)

Comment: I know this is for Amazon RDS, but there is a section about disabling constraints: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html that might be useful.

Comment: that was exactly what the doctor ordered, there were specific snippets for adding and removing all constraints, if you put those with that link into a post I'll mark it as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this link is for Amazon RDS, it does provide specific code to disable constraints without `sp_MSForEachTable`

[Importing and Exporting SQL Server Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html%22Importing%20and%20Exporting%20SQL%20Server%20Data%22)

```
-- Manually specify database name - a safeguard in case you paste this into the wrong SSMS window.
USE [staging]

-- Change this line if you want to enable (1) or disable constraints:
DECLARE @enable_constraints bit = 0

--Don't change anything below this line.
DECLARE @schema_name SYSNAME
DECLARE @table_name  SYSNAME

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    schemas.name,
    tables.name
FROM
    sys.tables
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id

OPEN table_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name

DECLARE @cmd varchar(200) 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' '
    SET @cmd = @cmd + (CASE WHEN @enable_constraints = 1 THEN 'CHECK' ELSE 'NOCHECK' END) + ' CONSTRAINT ALL'

    PRINT @cmd
    EXEC( @cmd )

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name
END

CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

Comment: For disabling it should be

`SELECT @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+' WITH NO CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';`

And for re-enabling it should be:

`SELECT @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+' WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';`

Comment: Actually correction. The disabling code doesn't need the "WITH". The re-enabling does.

Comment: NO CHECK should be one word:   `SELECT @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';`

Comment: and for re-enable the check?

Answer (score 2):

Extended the script to deal with tables in different schemas, also corrected the above script that is not disabling checks:

```
    -- DISABLE ALL CONSTRAINTS 
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @schema_name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT s.name, t.name 
    FROM sys.tables t
    join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id

OPEN table_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
  SELECT @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@schema_name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
  EXEC (@cmd);
  FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO  @schema_name, @table_name;
END

CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;


-- enable all constraints
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT s.name, t.name 
    FROM sys.tables t
    join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id

OPEN table_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @schema_name, @table_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
  SELECT @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@schema_name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table_name)+' CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
  EXEC (@cmd);
  FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO  @schema_name, @table_name;
END

CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```